# Face detection and face recognition technology in phoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want to measure a face parts like distances between two eyes, nose, lips length and height.
for that i like to use one template.

Please let me know if there is any way to implement this technology in Phonegap framework.

Do any phonegap-plugin available in market.
OR
give me an ideas to implement such tool.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a iOs plugin.
It returns an array of faces
Each face has the face rectangle and the eyes and mouth points

[Face Detect plugin](http://goo.gl/mCVij)